# How do I enter N carriage returns during a substitution?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

When using :s, how do I multiply the string being written by an integer, to write N copies of it?

For example, `:s/pattern/10*\r/` would write 10 carriage returns in each match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `repeat` function with replace expression:

```
%s/\n\_s*$/\=repeat("\r", 10)
```

Check `:h sub-replace-expression` and `:h repeat()` for details.

Comment: Thanks. Is the final enclosing slash omitted because it's always optional in the :s command or because it's not used for the repeat function?

Comment: The former—its optional in vim (maybe ex/vi, even ed?? It’s not optional in sed) when you provide no flags for `:substitute `

Comment: For sure, will do that going forward